# Calculating row difference and insert into new column in R (without using for loop)

Tags: r, loops

I have a huge dataset that I want to loop over each `user` in the first column and calculate `interval` column based on the difference (subtract) between each row with the next row of `start_time` column. The last row of each `user` can be 0 or NA because there is no other record after that `user`.

```
    df=read.table(text="
    user   start_time   
    1       4
    1       6
    1       10
    1       11
    2       1
    2       3
    2       5
    3       4
    3       4",header=T)

result
user   start_time  interval 
1       4          2 <-- (this is the result of 6-4)
1       6          3 <-- (9-6)
1       9          2 <-- (11-9)    
1       11         NA <-- (or can be 0) because it is last row of the user
2       1          2
2       3          3
2       6          NA <-- (or 0)
3       4          0
3       4          NA <--(or 0)
```

I would prefer something fast like group_by function.
How can I do it in R?

Comment: check out `diff`?

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(interval = lead(start_time) - start_time)
` If you replace `lag` in the marked answer with `lead` all of them would work. For `shift`, use `type = "lead"` (default is `"lag"`).  If you use `diff` do `c(diff(x), 0)` instead of `c(0, diff(x))`

Comment: use `data.table` , `setDT(df)[, diff := shift(start_time, type='lead')-start_time, .(user)]`